# Como remover o primeiro valor dentro de um array?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "VALOR 1"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "VALOR 2"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "VALOR 3"
}
```

Preciso mostrar todos os valores desse array porém excluir o primeiro, que no caso é o "VALOR 1". Como remover o primeiro valor do array? Sendo que a string pode ser qualquer coisa.

Tentei utilizar o **array_shift()** porém ele acaba sumindo com o meu array e deixando somente a primeira string.

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer remover o elemento ou não? o `array_shift()` remove o primeiro elemento.

Comment: @rray, eu preciso manter um array porém sem o valor [0]

Comment: Precisa manter a chave (`0`) vazia, seria isso?

Comment: @rray, isso, a chave 0 com por exemplo somente " ".

Comment: O array é sempre númerico? a chave zero sempre é a primeira?

Comment: a 0 é sempre a primeira sim, eu preciso mostrar todas as strings dentro do array, menos a primeira string

Comment: `$arr = array('valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3');
if(!empty($arr[0])) $arr[0] = '';` esse código server ou tem algum problema?

Comment: @rray, é isso mesmo

Comment: Não bastaria apenas setar o primeiro array como vazio?  `$arr[0] = null;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php), mas tome cuidado pra não sobrescrever o array, porque ele retorna o elemento retirado, não o array resultante.

Ou seja:

```
$arraycompleto = [1,2,3];

// Edit: se você precisa manter um valor qualquer na primeira posição 
// e a chave é sempre 0, isso vai resolver:
$arraycompleto[0] = '';
var_dump( $arraycompleto ); // ['',2,3]

// Se a primeira chave não é zero ou você precisa do valor original:
$elementoretirado = array_shift( $arraycompleto );
array_unshift( $arraycompleto, '' );

var_dump( $arraycompleto ); // ['',2,3]
var_dump( $elementoretirado ); // 1;
```

Comment: acredito que não expliquei direito mas eu preciso do array original com as três chaves, porém com a primeira string vazia ou nula.

Comment: acho que agora vai resolver